# React - REST Defined List of components by REST

Tags: rest, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm going to explain what I'am trying to achieve in my Flux/React application.

This is my routing :

```
var routes = (  
<Route name="layout" path="/" handler={Layout}> 
    <Route name="page" path=':section/:detail' handler={Page} />        

    <Route name="login" path='/login' handler={Login}/>

    <DefaultRoute handler={Layout}/>
</Route>
);
exports.start = function() {

  Router.run(routes, function (Handler, state) {
    var params = state.params;
    React.render(<Handler params={params}/>, document.body);
  });
}
```

I have a REST service that is giving returning an Array of components described as objects :

```
{
    "components" : {
        "header" : {
            //data
        },
        "tabs" : {
            //data
        }
    } 
}
```

Basically I tough to have a Page.jsx component that can handle the data given from the REST API and define the page structure.

I'm having trouble understanding how to manage the whole flow.

1. Where should I retrive the data ?

   - In the getInitialState ?
   - In the componentDidMount ?
   - In the Render ?

2  Render a component :

I'm trying to manage like this :

```
var avaibleComponents = {
        header : "header",
        tabs : "tabs"
    };

var components = data.components;
var element = React.createElement(avaibleComponents[i]);
var rendered = React.render(element, document.getElementById('rsec-page-container'));
```

So basically I'm a bit confused, wondering if anyone could help me out somehow.

Thanks

Comment: This is covered in the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

Comment: @WiredPrairie uhm not really

Comment: The section on retrieving data via Ajax? What isn't covered?